# how to set focus on a specific index in list view?

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to set focus on a specific index on list view. I am trying a scenario where I have buttons for up and down when I press the button Up I want to set the focus on upper index of the list view and the  same goes for the down button press. I have researched a lot on the internet but I have not been able to find any useful resource. Any suggestions to move the focus between the list view nodes/indexes will be really appreciated.

Comment: Use setSelection(-) it may helps.

Comment: @Nag:can I set the focus on the specific nodes of the listview using this method??

Answer (score 1):

If there is no any selection on listview for first time you can set selected position as 0, on down button press you can increase position by 1 and decrease by 1 for UP button press.

listview.setSelection(position);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

This will work for you.

Comment: @
 
Vishal Kharat: I have tried this but doesnot highlight item at 0 index  list.setSelection(0);

Comment: Can u please share your piece of code? So that it will be better to figure it out.